# How can I prevent automatic carriage returns (line wrapping) after copy/pasting web.config XML nodes?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, formatting, web-config, config, word-wrap

How can one prevent automatic carriage returns for copy/pasted web.config XML nodes?

Notice how each attribute is on a new line in the pasted snippet of code (from the web.config file)

**Copy this:**

```
<navigationGraph iViewManager="WebFormViewManager" name="PrintCOCs" state="State" statePersist="SqlServerPersistState" startView="1PrintCOC Set Preferences" endView="3PrintCOC Finished" cacheExpirationMode="Absolute" cacheExpirationInterval="12:00:00">
    <node view="1PrintCOC Set Preferences">
        <navigateTo navigateValue="Cancel" view="Supplies Dashboard" />
        <navigateTo navigateValue="PrintCOCs" view="2PrintCOC Print Chain of Custodies" />
    </node>
    <node view="2PrintCOC Print Chain of Custodies">
        <navigateTo navigateValue="Back" view="1PrintCOC Set Preferences" />
        <navigateTo navigateValue="Finished" view="3PrintCOC Finished" />
    </node>
    <node view="3PrintCOC Finished">
        <navigateTo navigateValue="Finished" view="Supplies Dashboard" />
    </node>
</navigationGraph>
```

**And this is what it looks like after being pasted:**

```
<navigationGraph iViewManager="WebFormViewManager"
                 name="PrintCOCs"
                 state="State"
                 statePersist="SqlServerPersistState"
                 startView="1PrintCOC Set Preferences"
                 endView="3PrintCOC Finished"
                 cacheExpirationMode="Absolute"
                 cacheExpirationInterval="12:00:00">
    <node view="1PrintCOC Set Preferences">
        <navigateTo navigateValue="Cancel"
                    view="Supplies Dashboard" />
        <navigateTo navigateValue="PrintCOCs"
                    view="2PrintCOC Print Chain of Custodies" />
    </node>
    <node view="2PrintCOC Print Chain of Custodies">
        <navigateTo navigateValue="Back"
                    view="1PrintCOC Set Preferences" />
        <navigateTo navigateValue="Finished"
                    view="3PrintCOC Finished" />
    </node>
    <node view="3PrintCOC Finished">
        <navigateTo navigateValue="Finished"
                    view="Supplies Dashboard" />
    </node>
</navigationGraph>
```

Comment: This is a setting somewhere under formatting, if you're talking about Visual Studio.

Comment: yes, this is in Visual Studio 2008.  That's what i'm having trouble finding.

Comment: They take up a lot of room in the web.config--several pages sometimes.  I'm configuring navigation flows, and we have hundreds to define in the web.config.  If we also have line breaks per attribute, that exponentially makes the file larger and more difficult to read.

Comment: My workaround is to not use Visual Studio.. I'm just using TextPad to copy/paste them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2008, this is under *Tools => Options => Text Editor => XML => Formatting => Attributes*. But it looks like your original XML is too wide for its own good. :)

Comment: If you have *Align...* selected but *On paste...* unchecked, then the *Format Document* action (^K^D) will still arrange the attributes the way you don't want them.